# Why It throws an error lvalue is required?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i=0,j=1;
    printf("%d",++(i+j));
    return 0;
}
```

In this code I have used the increment operator but i don't know why it throws an error.

It throws the error:

> lvalue is required.

Comment: Increment operator requires an lvalue as its operand, i.e. it requires a *variable* that you want to update. What were you trying to say by applying `++` to `i + j`? What exactly did you try to increment?

Comment: You cannot pre-increment `(i+j)` but you can add `1` to their sum, such as `1+(i+j)`.

Comment: The compiler gets angry because you tried `++(1)`.

Comment: If '++(i+j)' was allowed, what value would you expect 'i' to have afterwards?  What value would you expect 'j' to have afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to increment an integer value that isn't assigned to a variable.

Taking your code, this is approximately what the computer will try to do:

```
printf("%d",++(i+j));

// expanded step 1
printf("%d",++(0+1));

// expanded step 2
printf("%d",++(1));
```

As you can see in the last version, you are trying to call `++1`, which is invalid.

In order to increment a value using `++`, the operand must have integral, floating, or pointer type and must be a modifiable l-value expression (an expression without the const attribute):

```
int x = i+j;
printf("%d",++x);
```

Alternatively, you can use the addition operator:

```
printf("%d",i+j+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C you cannot apply an unary operator too a number. When the value between the parentesis is evaluated first... before use the unary operation. assing the result to a variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i=0,j=1, other_value=0;
    other_value = i+j;
    printf("%d",++(other_value));
    return 0;
}
```

Your previus code will work will get the error

```
error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

Comment: Re "*In C you cannot apply an unary operator too a number*", Not true: `!0`, `~0`

Answer (score 0):

You cant increment the result.

Instead:

```
   printf("%d",i + j + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

An "lvalue" is a value that can be the target of an assignment. The "l" stands for "left", as in the left hand side of the equals sign. An rvalue is the right hand value and produces a value, and cannot be assigned to directly. If you are getting "lvalue required" you have an expression that produces an rvalue when an lvalue is required.

in your case when compiler manipulate the expression then it will result to invalid expression which is ++1

try below:

printf("%d",i+j+1);

Answer (score 0):

The expression `++(i+j)` is not assignable. Here, the expression `(i+j)` will get evaluated first. For the `++` operator, the operand must have integral, floating, or pointer type and must be a modifiable l-value expression. Since the result from `i+j` is a constant value, so you get the error `lvalue required as increment operand`. You can choose to modify this expression as `i+j+1`.